# Zune Pass with Media Center

Tags: windows-media-center, zune

I would like to share a music folder on my network with my Media Center machine and play my Zune Pass music through the Media Center software.  The problem I am having is that since the music is DRM protected, Media Center has trouble playing the files unless the license for the file has been acquired (using Zune Pass on the Media Center).

I was hoping there was a Media Center extension for the Zune software or some other integration point to allow for this.

Has anyone ever done this? It would be great if Media Center and Zune Pass would play nice together.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not a totally smooth experience, but if you can acquire the license through the Zune client on your Media Center machine, you should be able to play the song in Media Center (or Windows Media Player).

I guess the big problem is acquiring licenses for all those songs on your Media Center machine.  You could probably do that by playing everything in the Zune client and just hitting "next" as soon as the song starts playing.  You might be able to do this in PowerShell, if you're so inclined.

I wish it was easier to do something like this.